# UIView With Multiple DrawRect Methods

Tags: ios, drawrect, cgcontext

I'm currently trying to create a Grid/Cinematic Overlay with a UIView.

I created a few methods; drawVerticalLine and Horizontal Lines and stuff...

I have a UIViewController that inits the UIGridView. I can put all my methods in the draw rect and draw them all at once.

However, I want to be able to call them individually from the ViewController. When I try to do`enter code here` that. I get an ": CGContextDrawPath: invalid context 0x0" Code Below.
From my ViewController I want to be able to call "drawGrid :withColor :andLines;" Or something

```
    -

(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect 
{

    if (self.verticalLinesON == YES) {
        [self drawVerticalLinesForGrid:100 :[UIColor redColor] :[UIColor greenColor]];

    }

    [self show16NineOverLay:[UIColor orangeColor]];

    [self show4ThreeOverLay:[UIColor orangeColor]];

    [self drawHorizontalLinesForGrid:100 :[UIColor blueColor] :[UIColor yellowColor]];

}
-(void)drawVerticalLinesForGrid:(float)sectionsVertically :(UIColor *)lineColor1 :(UIColor *)lineColor2
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2);
    int i = 0;
    float amountOfSectionsVertically = sectionsVertically;
    for (i = 1; i < amountOfSectionsVertically; i++)
    {//Horizontal Lines first.
        float xCoord = self.frame.size.width * ((i+0.0f)/amountOfSectionsVertically);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, xCoord, 0);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, xCoord, self.frame.size.height);
        if (i%2  == 1)
        {//if Odd
            CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, lineColor1.CGColor);
        }
        else if(i%2  == 0)
        {//if Even
            CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, lineColor2.CGColor);
        }
        CGContextStrokePath(context);
    }
}
-(void)drawHorizontalLinesForGrid :(float)sectionsHorizontally :(UIColor *)lineColor1 :(UIColor *)lineColor2
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2);
    int i = 0;
    float amountOfSectionsHorizontally = sectionsHorizontally;
    for (i = 1; i < amountOfSectionsHorizontally; i++)
    {//Vertical Lines first.
        float yCoord = self.frame.size.height * ((i+0.0f)/amountOfSectionsHorizontally);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, yCoord);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.frame.size.width, yCoord);
        if (i%2  == 1)
        {//if Odd
            CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, lineColor1.CGColor);
        }
        else if(i%2  == 0)
        {//if Even
            CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, lineColor2.CGColor);
        }
        CGContextStrokePath(context);
    }
}
-(void)show16NineOverLay:(UIColor *)lineColor
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 10);
    //x/y
    float yCoord = (0.5) * (self.frame.size.height * (1.778)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is set some state on your grid view class that specifies what should be drawn (just vertical, just horizontal, both, etc) and then call `setNeedsDisplay` on the view.

This will trigger a call to `drawRect:`. Then your `drawRect:` method should look at its current state and call just the appropriate methods to draw the desired parts.

You must never directly call `drawRect:` on a view.

Comment: Yeah, that was my work around. I made "setgrid/vertlines/otherstuff" methods and added them all to the ViewDidLoad. I put them inside of If Statements and created BOOL vars to decide whether or not they should be called. I set those BOOL as well as Line thickness, color